# Multple users accessing a method in Java

Tags: java

a little newbie from backend java. Suppose to be, I have web application, and if a user do a transaction it will go through `processMethod`.. For example, if I have 100k users creating transactions at almost the same time. Will they be go trough the processMethod one by one? or at the same time?

```
public class MyClass {

    private String processMethod(String a) {
         //do something.
    }

}
```

Comment: 100k users creating transactions at once? Who are you, Google? ;-) — In all seriousness, even moderately large sites rarely have more than a handful users who query the service at exactly the same time. Still, a server obviously needs to cope with the resulting concurrency. How this is done depends on your web framework.

Comment: Every user will have his own instance in the memory, so no one will wait for another one until the memory (RAM) is full then the newcomers will wait till there is a space there. This is only a very general concept to understand how it is done, otherwise, you need to learn more about the operating systems or in java case, the JDK, JRE

Comment: A "standard" Java web server has 1 request = 1 thread. All request will start a new concurrent thread to serve the response.
You can program a multithreaded web server in Java by yourself (good exercise to understand Java web servers) https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreaded-servers-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

Typically a Web application server uses threads to handle multiple requests at a time.

To answer your question: **No, calls to a method across threads are not blocked.** Multiple threads may be executing that method at the same time. If any resources are being shared across those threads including non-local variables, then you have a concurrency problem. Your code must be written in such a way as to protect access to any and all shared resources.

Concurrency is an advanced topic that requires much learning. You’ll need to learn about threads, the `Atomic…` classes, “visibility”, the Java Memory Model, and more. Required reading includes this excellent book, [*Java Concurrency In Practice*](https://jcip.net/) by Brian Goetz et al.

If you are certain that you are *not* sharing resources across threads, then you need not master those topics now. Though you should learn the basics of threading to understand performance when deployed in production.